# How to get all records of all post types in wp block

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I need to get posts of all types of a specified taxonomy term in my custom wp block.

I've tried looping getEntityRecords(), substituting a new postType in the arguments each time, and adding the result to the posts array, but that doesn't work. I am getting null.

Tell me, is there any way to do this, some kind of function like getAllRecords(), which would take several types of posts in arguments?

```php
const myPosts = getEntityRecords('postType','post', 
    //here I would like insert array of my post types
    {
        ...my_additional_args,
        ...my_tax_query,
    }
);
```

I have also tried these solutions but none of these answers work for me.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/383176/how-to-query-multiple-post-types-inside-gutenberg-options-panel